# Как задать параметры отключения функций объекта через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здраствуйте такой вопрос. Я написал код в котором персонаж когда берет предмет(в моем случае молния) ускоряется, но это ускорение остается постоянным, как мне сделать так чтобы ускорение длилось к примеру секунду - полторы секунды?

/Это код объекта который ускоряет игрока

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

```
public class SpeedBoost : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject speedBoost;
    public int itemValue = 5;
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)

    {
        PlayerRun PlayerRunScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerRun>();
        StartCoroutine(PlayerRunScript.UpdateSpeedForInterval(5, 3f));
        Destroy(speedBoost);
    
    }
}
```

/Это код игрока

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class PlayerRun : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public float SpeedPlayer = 5.0f;
    public FixedJoystick joystick;
    public float RightLeftSpeed = 5.0f;
    private int Life = 100;
    public Text Life_State;

    

    void Start()
    {
        print("Start Life " + Life);


    }

    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(joystick.Direction.x * SpeedPlayer * Time.deltaTime, 0, SpeedPlayer * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    public void updateLife(int puntos)
    {
        Life += puntos;
        print("Current Life " + Life);
        Life_State.text = Life.ToString();
        isAlive();
    }
    private void isAlive()
    {
        if (Life <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("StartScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator UpdateSpeedForInterval(int speed, float time)
    {
       

        SpeedPlayer += speed;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        SpeedPlayer -= speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: как отредактировать вопрос?

Comment: Изменил вопрос, прикрепил код

Comment: Александр, согласно правилам сайта вы должны погуглить вопрос перед тем как его задавать? Неужели по запросу "Таймер в Unity" вам не выдало информации про корутины?

Comment: Не буду давать свой овтет, но спрошу: Какие именно ошибки у вас есть прямо сейчас, после диалога с Сергеем?

Comment: Ошибок нет как таковых, просто код не работает, ничего не меняется, скорость после ускорения так и остается постоянно ускоренной

Answer (score 2):

Например через корутины (https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/Coroutines.html) и метод `WaitForSeconds` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

```
IEnumerator UpdateSpeedForCertainTime(int speed, float time) {
    SpeedPlayer += speed;
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    SpeedPlayer -= speed;   
}
```

---

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    // .....
    StartCoroutine(PlayerRunScript.UpdateSpeedForInterval(5, 1.5f));    
}
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Comment: Если это помогло - можно пометить галочкой ответ

Comment: не помогло, скорость осталась неизменной, может я что то не так сделал хм

Comment: Ах, да. Надо в метод передать данные. Например `StartCoroutine(PlayerRunScript.UpdateSpeedForInterval(5, 1.5f));`

Comment: Выдает вот такую ошибку: Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка CS1501 Ни одна из перегрузок метода "UpdateSpeedForInterval" не принимает 3 аргументов. Assembly-CSharp D:\Games\unity others\New Unity Project\Assets\Script\SpeedBoost.cs 16 Активные

Comment: вы даёте на вход три аргумента, вместо двух

Comment: А вот это что значит? 
Ошибка CS0122 "PlayerRun.UpdateSpeedForInterval(int, float)" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты. Assembly-CSharp

Comment: сделайте его public вместо private

Comment: Я не знаю, все перепробовал синтаксис правильный, оишбок не выдает, но все по прежнему не работает

Comment: @Александр возможно на player должен быть ещё компонент `rigidBOdy` без гравитации  --- "To have collision between two of your objects one of them has to have a rigidbody component." Накиньте на игрока его.. попробуйте

Comment: еще один компонет rigidbody или уже в существующем поставить галочку?

Comment: Если есть , то не надо.... но мой код рабочий.  всё что я знаю надо коллайдеры и rigidbody

Comment: Извиняюсь, не очень понял, что нужно накинуть на игрока в компонентах еще раз? Второй риджетбоди не добавляется

Comment: не понял конкретно что значит эта строка To have collision between two of your objects one of them has to have a rigidbody component.

Comment: Ну откройте переводчик пожалуйста и скопируйте фразу туда

Comment: У меня не получается накинуть два риджитбоди на одного игрока

Comment: Что я не так делаю

Comment: Если уже есть, то не надо